# Can I downgrade Galaxy A10s from stock Recovery?

Tags: samsung, recovery-mode, android-10, device-firmware, android-11

I have `Samsung Galaxy A10s (SM-A107F)`. In the summer I updated to `Android 11` (current firmware is `A107FXXS8CVK1`, `SEK` region). Now I want to roll back to `Android 10`, but I don’t have a computer, root and TWRP. Is it possible, for example, to download the firmware from [here](https://samfw.com/firmware/SM-A107F/SEK/A107FXXS8BUC1) (version `A107FXXS8BUC1`, `SEK` region) and install it via `Apply update from SD card` in stock Recovery? And will I lose data on the phone or on the memory card, or both?

---

**UPD**: I want to downgrade because in `Android 11` there is no access to some folders due to `Scoped Storage`.

---

**UPD**: I also want to downgrade because I liked `One Ui 2` better.

Comment: Can you please tell us why you want to downgrade so we better understand the issue?

Comment: @zomega I want to downgrade because in Android 11 there is no access to some folders due to scoped storage

Comment: There is a new permission called [MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) on Android 11 so apps can still access the external storage. See this screenshot https://imgur.com/a/P1PJnCP A good file explorer supports this. So you can still access all files as before Android 11. If this doesn't help you, you can root your phone which gives you access to all files (even system files for example). Good file explorers support root access. Downgrading is not a good idea in this case as it doesn't seem to be necessary.

Comment: @zomega I still want to downgrade. I liked One Ui 2 better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are drawbacks when you downgrade:

- you will loose security updates
- firmwares from the internet can contain viruses
- you will loose all data (downgrade performs factory reset)
- if something goes wrong your phone is bricked
- There will be a warning screen on boot which tells the user that you modified the firmware. This warning cannot be removed once you enabled OEM unlocking. When you sell your phone you will get less money because of this warning. (Update: It's possible that flashing official firmware does not enable this warning. Also see comments.)

If you still want to downgrade you have to do it on your own risk:

1. backup all your data
2. enable developer settings
3. enable OEM unlocking in the developer settings
4. boot into download mode
5. start the tool Odin on your PC
6. flash firmware

I don't have the time to write a detailed tutorial but you can find many guides on the internet. One can be found [here](https://medium.com/@admin_32688/how-to-flash-samsung-firmware-using-odin-samsung-firmware-6523ca3be1c6). Simply search for "Samsung flash odin" on the web.

Comment: In your list of negative consequence the "Knox flag is permanently triggered". This means certain Kox based function will no longer work (mostly in an MDM context).

Comment: @Robert I've read if you load a non-Knox kernel the knox bit is triggered. Does this mean flashing official firmware (which have knox kernels) don't trigger the knox bit? https://docs.samsungknox.com/admin/knox-platform-for-enterprise/faqs/faq-115013562087.htm

Comment: In my understanding Knox bit should not be triggered by official firmware. But there should be downgrade protection so the number of possible firmware you can install should be very limited. But I have to admit that I don't have practical experience on that field as I have many Samsung devices.